# Not Acceptable link after redirecting from Google drive auth

Tags: php, google-drive-api

**Here is my code to authenticate,**

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
$client->setRedirectUri("https://example.com/google_redirect");
$client->setClientId("my-client-id");
$client->setClientSecret("my-client-secret");
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
```

**I can connect with this. But after authorizing from Google, it's redirecting like this,**

https://example.com/google_redirect?code=4%2F0AY0e_i_have_changed_some_code_for_security_reason_6_d83BTJiyKKIHFsCb8l61xW71kyOPW3g&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive#

**The page is showing this message:**

[image]

I guess, I could fix this error message by applying anything from here: [Not Acceptable! An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090737/not-acceptable-an-appropriate-representation-of-the-requested-resource-could-no/28148890)

But this is not the convenient way. Every user should do that.

Is there any special parameter or something to prevent this or get data by POST method in Google?

Looking for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your cookie settings.

Comment: I don't know what is the reason. But after trying 3-4 times, it worked.

Comment: It did work without any changes? Did you modify the cookie settings?

Comment: I didn't change anything.